# Allow special characters in asp .net 3.5

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, special-characters

When I am passing special characters like `"<" & "%"` in the URL I am getting 400 bad request.

In my page its like 1 search box. And there is button next to it. If user enters some value then I am passing that value to another page as a query string and then perform search on that page.

But I am getting

> 400 bad request error for special characters.

I have tried using `encodeURIcomponent` , `escape` functions of javascript too.
Still it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing data into `QueryString` you may pass data from one page to another by using `Session` as well.Set the Value in `Session` from `page1` and get it easily on `page2` and perform your `search` action easily.

I don't know that this is the exact answer of your question but this is also a way  to complete your task as well.

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

From your tags specified in your question, I am assuming that you are using asp.net

Therefore you can overcome your problem using a page directive

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ValidateRequest="false" %>
```

However it does open your site up to script attacks. You will need to be very careful how you store and display the data submitted.